# How to fix "element is not expected" in a CMS page with no XML changes?

Tags: magento2, admin, xml, cms-pages

I'm receiving this error message which is mentioned below, but as you can see in the image there are no XML updates, neither content, how can I fix it?

> Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'reference': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move, head, body ). Line: 1

[image: Magento2 This element is not expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is an old XML in the database, check the **cms_page** table in the **custom_layout_update_xml**. When you find and remove the XML changes directly from the database it will be solved and you might be able to save your CMS Page normally.

[image: Magento2 This element is not expected fixed]

It's happening because you updated your Magento and it was saved there before, this updated version didn't recognize the XML to render in the page to be removed or edited.